Circle bundle over $\Bbb CP^n$ whose total space is $S^{2n+1}$
Viewing $S^{2n+1}$ as the unit sphere in $\Bbb C^{n+1}$, the natural projection $S^{2n+1}\to \Bbb CP^n$, the generalized Hopf fibration, is a circle bundle. What I am curious about is its converse. Suppose we have an $S^1$ fiber bundle over $\Bbb CP^n$ whose total space is homeomorphic to $S^{2n+1}$. Then does this bundle must be isomorphic to the Hopf bundle?
If I can show that such a bundle $S^{2n+1}\to \Bbb CP^n$ must be an orientable $S^1$-bundle, then it has a principal $S^1$-bundle structure (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144092/is-every-orientable-circle-bundle-principal), and thus we can compare its first Chern number, etc. But I'm not sure whether such bundle must be orientable or not.

I think any $S^1$ bundle with total space $S^{2n+1}$ must be orientable. Consider the Serre spectral sequence for any such fibration, so it's starting page is $E^{p,q}_2=H^p(\mathbb{CP}^n,\mathscr{H}^q(S^1))$, where this $\mathscr{H}^q$ is the local system on the base of the $q$th cohomology group of the fibre. In particular, the bundle is orientable iff the sheaf $\mathscr{H}^1(S^1)$ is constant, iff there exists a global section of this sheaf, which is to say, iff $H^0(\mathbb{CP}^n,\mathscr{H}^1(S^1))$ is nonzero.
So now if we had a non orientable such bundle, this cohomology group would vanish. Computing $H^2$ of the total space via the spectral sequence shows then that this second cohomology group must be $\mathbb{Z}$, so the total space can't be $S^{2n+1}$, giving the result.

Since $\det (A \oplus B) = \det A \det B$, orientability satisfies many "any two out of three" rules. In the context of the question, if a bundle over an orientable base has an orientable total space then it must be orientable. This follows by orienting the trivializing charts according to the orientations of the total space and then comparing the transition maps, which are the identity, in particular oriented, on the base.
Presumably you already know that $\mathbb{C}P^n$ and $S^{2n + 1}$ are orientable.
